# Search through selected cells and hide them if they contain a letter

Tags: excel, vba

I want to loop through cells and look for letters. If they contain the letter hide the cell with NumberFormat. This works but how do I make this loop toggeable so i can hide/unhide.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Set rng = Range("D5:F35,D43:F73,J5:L35,J43:L73,P5:R35,P43:R73,V5:X35,V43:X73,AB5:AD35,AB43:AD73,AH5:AJ35,AH43:AJ73")
For Each cell In rng
        If InStr(1, cell.Value, "A") > 0 Then cell.NumberFormat = ";;;"
        If InStr(1, cell.Value, "B") > 0 Then cell.NumberFormat = ";;;"
        If InStr(1, cell.Value, "C") > 0 Then cell.NumberFormat = ";;;"
        If InStr(1, cell.Value, "D") > 0 Then cell.NumberFormat = ";;;"
        If InStr(1, cell.Value, "F") > 0 Then cell.NumberFormat = ";;;"
Next cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "toggeable"
If you want to unhide everything, no matter what it contains, then just set the .numberformat property of the entire range to General.

If you mean that when you remove one of the target letters from the cell, that it should become unhidden, then try this macro below:

**EDIT**  Edited to add what I think you mean by toggle.

========================================

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Binary
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Set rng = Range("D5:F35,D43:F73,J5:L35,J43:L73,P5:R35,P43:R73,V5:X35,V43:X73,AB5:AD35,AB43:AD73,AH5:AJ35,AH43:AJ73")

Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = ";;;"
Set cell = rng.Find(what:="*", searchformat:=True)
    If Not cell Is Nothing Then
        rng.NumberFormat = "General"
        Exit Sub
    End If

For Each cell In rng
       If cell.Value Like "*[ABCDEF]*" Then
            cell.NumberFormat = ";;;"
        Else
            cell.NumberFormat = "General"
        End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

====================================

Comment: By toggable I want to hide and unhide with the same button. the command  cell.NumberFormat = "General" under the Else statement does not make it unhide again. But the If statement works as it should.

Comment: @oppsig I have added code to my answer that should accomplish what I think you mean by "toggable".  If that is not the case, please clarify with more specific information.

Comment: @oppsig  The statement under `Else` is designed to unhide a cell if you should remove the key letters from that cell.  Are you writing that it does not work that way on your system?  If not, please indicate specifically how you tested it.

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Set rng = Range("D5:F35,D43:F73,J5:L35,J43:L73,P5:R35,P43:R73,V5:X35,V43:X73,AB5:AD35,AB43:AD73,AH5:AJ35,AH43:AJ73")

For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value Like "*A*" Or cell.Value Like "*B*" Or cell.Value Like "*C*" Or cell.Value Like "*D*" Or cell.Value Like "*F*" Then
        cell.NumberFormat = ";;;"
    End If
Next cell

End Sub



Sub Macro1()

If cell.NumberFormat = ";;;" Then
    cell.NumberFormat = "General"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This hides the entire row, i just want to hide the cell content like cell.NumberFormat = ";;;" does. But If it is already hidden i want to show it.

Answer (score 0):

The last part of the number format is for text - just remove that part from your custom number format to hide/show text.

```
Sub HideText()

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") _
        .Range("D5:F35,D43:F73,J5:L35,J43:L73,P5:R35,P43:R73,V5:X35,V43:X73,AB5:AD35,AB43:AD73,AH5:AJ35,AH43:AJ73")

    If rng.NumberFormat <> "#,##0;-#,##0;#,##0;" Then
        rng.NumberFormat = "#,##0;-#,##0;#,##0;"
    Else
        rng.NumberFormat = "#,##0;-#,##0;#,##0;@"
    End If

End Sub
```